# How to pass arguments when instantiating a class to a function in Python?

Tags: python, arguments

I have tried to portray and document each class only what is necessary, hope you can help me please, I am trying to **instantiate** the **class**
`Show_image` which requires two parameters,
two indexes of a list of images, if you could guide me if what I am trying to do is possible I would appreciate it. Thanks.

**This class resizes the image**

```py
from tkinter importante *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Array(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, path, *args):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args)       self.image = Image.open(path)
        self.img_copy = self.image.copy()

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.background = Label(self, image=self.background_image)
        self.background.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.background.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

    def _resize_image(self, event):
        self.image = self.img_copy .resize ((self.master .winfo_width(), self.master .winfo_height()))

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background.configure(image=self.background_image)
```

**Base class control**

```py
class Interface(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args)
        self.path_lst = ['11.png','22.png','33.png','44.png']  # change/add paths 
        self._frame_1 = None
        self._open_1 = False
        self.button1 = Button(self, text='pack 1',
                      command= lambda:self.windows(Show_image))
        self.button1 .pack()
 
    def windows(self, var_1):
        if not self._open_1:
            self.top1 = Toplevel(self.master)
            self.top1 .geometry('200x200')
                                
        container = var_1(self.top1)

        if self._frame_1 is not None:  
            self._frame_1 .destroy()
        self._frame_1 = container
        self._frame_1 .pack()
        self._open_1 = True

        self.top1.protocol ('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', lambda: self.closed(1))
    
    def closed(self, number):
        if number == 1:
            self.top1. destroy()
            self._open_1 = False
```

**This class should draw two  instances, two images, but I don't know how to pass** `<index_1>` **and** `<index_2>` **arguments in bound** `<lambda>` **function.**

```py
class Show_image(Frame):
    def __init__(self, index_1, index_2, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.img = Array(self, self.master.path_lst[index_1])
        self.img .grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.img2 = Array(self, self.master.path_lst[index_2])
        self.img2 .grid(column=0, row=1)

root = Tk()
frm = Interface(root)
frm .pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Also, if you could tell me if the **initialization** path of the images is correct. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following; is this what you mean?

`self.button1 = Button(self, text='pack 1',
                      command= lambda:self.windows(Show_image(index_1, index_2, args, kwargs)))`

Comment: @Schalton Thanks for the help, but I'm afraid I'm doing something wrong with the ```<path_lst>``` list because the ```<Show_image>``` class doesn't recognize it and I'm throwing an error. Sorry it's another bug on my part, as soon as I solve it I'll test if ```<lambda top>``` works for me. Thanks for the help you give me, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understant you will have to use nested `lambdas`

```
command=lambda:self.windows(lambda:Show_image(index1, index2))
```

but I see that `windows` runs function with argument `top` so it will need it also in `lambda`

```
command=lambda:self.windows( lambda top:Show_image(index1, index2, top))
```

---

**EDIT:**

Full working code with other changes.

I send `master` as first value and `path_lst` as last value and I don't need to use `self.master.pack_lst`

I changed some `pack()`, `grid()` and I added `grid_rowconfigure()` so it correctly resize images when window change size.

I used `os.listdir()` to create `path_lst`. It uses `sys.argv` to get `folder` from command line (`python script.py path_to_images`) or it uses `os.getcwd()` to get `Current Working Directory` as `folder`

I changed name to `ShowImage` as suggest `PEP8` - `CamelCaseNames` for classes.

I'm not sure if it suggests to use `noun` for classes (like noun `ImageViewer` instead of verb `ShowImage`) and `verb` for functions (like verb `show_window` instead of noun `windows`) but I skip it. Maybe it is suggestion in book ['Clean Code' by Robert C. Martin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) (also known as [Uncle Bob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_C._Martin))

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

```py
import os   # os.path.join(), os.listdir()
import sys  # sys.argv
#from tkinter import *  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import tkinter as tk 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# --- constants ---  # PEP8: `UPPER_CASE_NAMES

#FOLDER = '/home/furas/test'

# --- classes ---  # PEP8: `CamelCaseNames` 

class Array(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, path, *args):
        super().__init__(master, *args)   # in Python 3 you can use `super()` without `self`
        
        self.image = Image.open(path)
        self.img_copy = self.image.copy()

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.background = tk.Label(self, image=self.background_image)
        self.background.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.background.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

    def _resize_image(self, event):
        self.image = self.img_copy.resize((self.master.winfo_width(), self.master.winfo_height()//2))

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background.configure(image=self.background_image)


class Interface(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, folder, *args):
        super().__init__(master, *args)
        
        self.folder = folder
        
        #self.path_lst = ['11.png','22.png','33.png','44.png']  # change/add paths
        self.path_lst = [os.path.join(self.folder, name) for name in os.listdir(self.folder) if name.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.gif'))]  # change/add paths
        
        self._frame_1 = None
        self._open_1 = False
        
        index_1 = 0
        index_2 = 1
        
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text='pack 1',
                      command=lambda:self.windows(lambda top:ShowImage(top, index_1, index_2, self.path_lst)))
        self.button1.pack()
 
    def windows(self, var_1):
        if not self._open_1:
            self.top1 = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
            self.top1.geometry('200x200')
                                
        container = var_1(self.top1)

        if self._frame_1 is not None:  
            self._frame_1.destroy()
            
        self._frame_1 = container
        self._frame_1.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self._open_1 = True

        self.top1.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', lambda: self.closed(1))
    
    def closed(self, number):
        if number == 1:
            self.top1.destroy()
            self._open_1 = False


class ShowImage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, index_1, index_2, path_lst, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        
        if len(path_lst) > index_1:
            self.img = Array(self, path_lst[index_1])
            self.img.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='news')
        
        if len(path_lst) > index_2:
            self.img2 = Array(self, path_lst[index_2])
            self.img2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='news')

        # column 0 will use full width
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # row 0 will use 1/2 height AND row 1 will use 1/2 height
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)     
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names`

# empty

# --- main ---

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    folder = sys.argv[1]
else:
    folder = os.getcwd()

#folder = FOLDER

root = tk.Tk()
frm = Interface(root, folder)
frm.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

**BTW:**

Because window has to display two images so I divide height by 2 (`self.master.winfo_height()//2`) in `Array` to fit both rows/images in window.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm afraid I'm doing something wrong with the ```<path_lst>``` list because the ```<Show_image>``` class doesn't recognize it and I'm throwing an error. Sorry it's another bug on my part, as soon as I solve it I'll test if ```<lambda top>``` works for me. Thanks for the help you give me, I appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, sure you have other things to do, but this syntax is valid if I intend to instantiate 3 objects of that ```<Show_image>``` class:
```command = lambda: self.windows (lambda top, top2, top3: Show_image (index1, index2, top, top2, top3))```

Comment: as for `path_lst`: you have `path_lst` in `Interface` and in `Show_image` you use `self.master.path_lst` but `Interface` is NOT master for `Show_image` - it would need to send `self` as argument `Show_image(index_1, index_2, self, top)` and then it will assign `self, top` to `*args` which will send `*args` to `Frame.__init__(...)` and it will assign first value from `*args` to `self.master`

Comment: Maybe you should do similar to `Array` and define `Show_image` as `def __init__(self, master, index_1, index_2, *args, **kwargs):` with `master as first argument and run it as `Show_image(self, index_1, index_2, top)` like you have in `Array` and in standard widget - ie. `self.button1 = Button(self, ....)`

Comment: BTW: you should also catch `top` in separated variable in `Show_init` because it catchs it as `*args` and it sends it to `Frame.__init__` and it doesn't know what to do with `top`.

Comment: BTW: currently for `.png`  you can use `tkinter.PhotoImage` and you don't need `PIL` but for other formats (ie. `.jpg`) you may still need `PIL`

Comment: I added full working code.

Comment: I have been doing my homework, ```lambda``` is a world for me, but in summary I have understood well the code that you have provided me. I am very grateful for it. I am interested in the ```syx.argv``` function, since it is understood that it returns a list, where [0]: the name of the path + name of the ```script```, understanding that it can also receive parameters. Can these parameters only be inserted by the console? What would the syntax look like? **Thank you so much for everything** .

Comment: `sys.argv` gets arguments which you use in console or when you use module `subprocess` to run script (or when other language use something similar to run your script with arguments). System uses `space` to split arguments. If you run `script.py arg1 arg2 arg3` then you get list `["script.py", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]`. But if you put text with `space` in `" "` like `script.py "Hello World" arg2 arg3` then you get list `["script.py", "Hello World", "arg2", "arg3"]`.

Comment: If you want to use complex parameters like `--input image.jpg`,`--path C:/` then you can use module [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)